# WKWebView's WKUrlSchemeHandler and Cookies with the Secure property

Tags: ios, cookies, wkwebview, nshttpcookie, wkurlschemehandler

Since iOS 11, you could use [WKURLSchemeHandler](http://%20https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkurlschemehandler?language=objc) with WKWebView:

> A protocol for loading resources with URL schemes that WebKit doesn't
>   know how to handle.

If you used a custom-scheme - let's say `foobarhttps` - WKWebView does NOT appear to treat it as Secure.

When a server response is received with a `Set Cookie` instruction, that Cookie is never attached to requests sent via `foobarhttps` if the Cookie had the property `isSecure:TRUE`.

Is there a WkWebView property I am missing that would allow requests via `foobarhttps` to include these Cookies?

```
<NSHTTPCookie
    version:1
    name:FOOBARCOOKIE
    value:ALICEANDBOB
    expiresDate:'(null)'
    created:'2019-11-13 17:10:08 +0000'
    sessionOnly:TRUE
    domain:.server.com
    partition:none
    path:/
    isSecure:TRUE
 path:"/" isSecure:TRUE>
```

**Update (closed)**
I had misunderstood the implications of setting a Cookie's property for a `subdomain` versus the `domain`.  All worked with `WKURLSchemeHandler`.

Anyway, I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain).